# Can't connect to wifi Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, network-manager

I have some troubles with the internet connection on my laptop. All the devices can easily connect to wi-fi while my laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 can not connect or it gets the connection, but for some reason the internet is very slow. This behavior can't be observed with other devices.
My computer kept switching the wi-fi on and off, that is why I have created this script, which I load when I turn on my computer:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

However, it didn't resolve my problem. So what could be the reasons of such behavior?

`iwconfig wlan0` command output

```
wlan0 
IEEE 802.11abgn ESSID:"WiFi #9"
Mode:Managed Frequency:2.412 GHz Access Point:74:D0:2B:5B:0A:F0
Bit Rate=65 Mb/s Tx-Power=22dBm
Retry long limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
Power Management:off
Link Quality=16/70  Signal level=-94 dBm
Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid flag:0
Tx excessive retries:169  Invalid misc:35  Missed beacon:0
```

**EDIT:**
`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; uname -r` command result

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless Ac 3160 [8086: 8470]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:06b0]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
3.13.0-141-generic
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; uname -r` and what is the manufacturer of the computer

Comment: @Jeremy31 I added command result to the question. The manufacturer is Dell